# Create table with numeric column

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqldatatypes

```sql
CREATE TABLE SampleMath
(m  NUMERIC (10,3),
 n  INTEGER,
 p  INTEGER);
```

Question: why there is a space between `NUMERIC` and `(10,3)`.

At first, I thought `(10,3)` is a column constraint. However, it doesn't seem to be correct as common constraints are `NOT NULL`, `UNIQUE` as listed [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_constraints.asp).

Then I thought that it could be the property (precision, scale) for the datatype `NUMERIC` as described in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html). In that case, I think there should not be a space between `NUMERIC` and `(10,3)`. I also tried to delete the space in between and it seems the code still works. In my understanding, if it is the property, there should not be a space, which makes me really confused.

Any help to clarify this would be really appreciated. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: SQL allows spaces between most operators and identifies, including between a type and its length (or precision and scale).

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know this before. Now everything is more clear to me.

Comment: . . I should add that newlines and tabs are also allowed.  Most languages work like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NUMERIC (10,3)` is a datatype. It can store a number with a total of 10 digits (that's called *precision*), including 3 decimal (aka *scale*, ie the count of digits at the right of the decimal point). So basically the biggest number that it can store is `9999999.999`.

The space between `NUMERIC` and the definition of its scale and precision is not meaningful. Even a new line would be OK, like:

```
CREATE TABLE SampleMath
(m  NUMERIC 
        (10,3),
 n  INTEGER,
 p  INTEGER);
```

Comment: Do you mean that it would be better to delete the space between `NUMERIC` and `(10,3)`. One follow-up question is why SQL doesn't raise an error if we add it, as it could have confused `(10,3)` as a constraint.

Comment: I mean that this space has no meaning for Postgres. You can have no space, one space, several spaces, that does not make a difference at all. About constraints, they have a different syntax, there is no risk of confusion.